# error in image_pipeline

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, image-pipeline, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Today i tried to get the OpenCV 2.4.3 (With CUDA 5.0) working with ROS Fuerte.
After i successful compile the OpenCV and test it i tried to compile a ROS program, but every program i compile (that uses the kinect) gives me this

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/joao/ros_workspace/sandbox/kinect_icp/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/kinect_track.dir/src/GetFeaturePoints.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/kinect_track.dir/src/kinect_track.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/kinect_track
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so:     error: undefined reference to 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so: error: undefined reference to 'boost::signals::connection::operator=(boost::signals::connection const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/kinect_track] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/joao/ros_workspace/sandbox/kinect_icp/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/kinect_track.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/joao/ros_workspace/sandbox/kinect_icp/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/joao/ros_workspace/sandbox/kinect_icp/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

This is with and without using the Opencv.
I also uninstall the Opencv 2.4.3, restart the pc and noting. I still get the same error...

Did i mess up with ROS or there was an update (that i didn't notice) that broke this?

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Edit:

I re-install every thing (even linux) and its the same thing.
On a fresh install its every thing OK. This time i installed CUDA 4.2 and PCL 1.7 (ros version) and now this happens again. So i'm  inclined to say its a problem related to CUDA (the common thing between the two "experiences")
I installed CUDA according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54490/error-in-image_pipeline/) by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

could be using namespace issue. Did you build your opencv directly with ROS in the CMAKE?  I experience something similiar before for error: undefined reference with openc v+ ros to some 3rd partry library. It turns out opencv shares couple library with ros. say boost under cv::boost and there is another ros::boost. of course your system gets confused.

I think to solve this. One is to build opencv not with ROS. So when you use it remember not to use using namespace cv;   but use every function as cv::boost.....
If above not working just remove opencv and compile without ROS and try it again

---

Originally posted by [snakehaihai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3261/snakehaihai/) with karma: 28 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on 2013-02-12**:
I re-install every thing including Linux itself and it seams to be related to the CUDA. booth CUDA 4.2 and 5.0